# Remove/hide tfoot last page only in html printing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have table with data its printing multiple pages every page `<tfoot>Some text</tfoot>` display end of the page. I want to remove/hide the `<tfoot>Some text</tfoot>` only in last page. Is there any way to do this with css/javascript?
I have tried many ways nothing works[image]

This is sample of what I want. I want to hide the footer while printing.

Comment: How do you identify which is the last page?

Comment: That too i need help. if i can find the last page i can able to do it

Comment: Is it one `<table>` that spreads over multiple print pages? Or are there several tables each on its own page?

Comment: one <table> that spreads over multiple print pages

Comment: @JohnRajan What is considered a last page? Is it the latest page that has been added or a page that you've determined to be last? Like, what is the condition for a page to be decided as a last page?

Comment: @JohnRajan Is the table the last element in your document? Or is it just the last appearance of the `<tfoot>`that you don't want to print?

Comment: @Gosi This table generated by for loop so when i click print according to the loop no of pages will print in that i want to hide the footer on last page

Comment: @yunzen last appearance of the <tfoot>'Some Text'</tfoot>that i don't want to print.i want hide the  "Some Text" only while printing

Comment: I don't think this is possible, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

If you consider that each page contains only one tfooter, you can try something like this:

```
// Select all tfooters
const footers = document.querySelectorAll('tfooter');
// Select the last one
const last =  footers[footers.length - 1];
// add a class to hide it
last.classList.add('hidden');
```

Comment: You can add a class that only works in a media query

`@media print {
 .hidden { display:none; }
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can just count the number of `<tfoot>` tag using javascript and just hide the last one.

Do something like this (jQuery example):

```
var count = $("#div tfoot").length; 
$("tfoot : " +count).hide();
```

Comment: You can [edit] you answer, don't post code in comments.

Answer (score 1):

To identify your last page, try to get a specific information in your URL then you can try something like this in Javascript :

First find the last page index :

```
var itemsCount = 15 -->here you have to get the count of all your elements store in your datatable
var itemPerPage = 6 --> the datatable pagesize

var pageMax = Math.ceil(itemsCount/itemPerPage);
18 items / 6 per page = 3 pages
19 items / 6 per page = 4 pages
```

Get the index parameter in your URL (refer to this:[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top)) :

```
//if your url look like this : http://localhost:5555/home?index=5&pageSize=18
var urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const myIndex= urlParams.get('index'); // = 3

if(pageMax == myIndex)
{
//hide your element <tfoot></tfoot>
}
```